# Python script running in one system will perform the result in another system

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to write a python script which when executes will open a Maya file in another computer and creates its playblast there. Is this possible? Also I would like to add one more thing that the systems I use are all Windows. Thanks

Comment: First thing that I would try is to create a service-like application on the other computer with Python's built-in HTTP server. Then, "local" script would create a request targeting the service by IP:port and the service will do what it is supposed to.

Comment: I quite frequently playblast all new files on the server. Is this a windows machine by any chance? Because you got a lot of linux answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, i do this all the time on several computers. First you need to access the computer. This has been answered. Then call maya from within your shell as follows:

```
maya -command myblast -file filetoblast.ma
```

you will need **myblast.mel** somewhere in your script path

myblast.mel:

```
global proc myblast(){
    playblast -widthHeight 1920 1080 -percent 100 
              -fmt "movie" -v 0 -f (`file -q -sn`+".avi"); 
    evalDeferred("quit -f");
}
```

Configure what you need in this file such as shading options etc. Please note calling Maya GUI uses up one license and playblast need that GUI (you could shave some seconds by not doing the default GUI)

Comment: Not a big deal, but he did ask for Python :)

Comment: How do you call Maya from within a Python script in Windows platform? Thanks

Comment: Same way as linux using a system call? Problem is that while maya has a python callable version it stars no GUI so it can not playblast

Comment: @ShannonHochkins sure but playblast only exists inside mayas gui and while it has a python interpretter you still need to start maya separayely and thus wether you playblast in mel or python changes little unless you want maya to run permanently. Im the only one who adresses playblasting. You can still call this from a python.

Comment: if it wasnt for playblast no prob, everything that doesent need the gui layer is a different thing.

Comment: @joojaa What do you use to connect to the remote machines when you work? I have been trying to use Paramiko but its not working and also I lack knowledge in this area. Could you plz guide me through this aw well? Thank you.

Comment: @zingy its imposiible for me to debug your settings describe what hangs does?

Comment: @joojaa I deleted the last comment. I apologize for writing a message which was difficult to understand. I am trying the rpyc method. Also I used the telnet library but I always get the same error which is "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". I checked the firewall settings too.

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute something on a remote computer, you've got to have some sort of service running there.

If it is a linux machine, you can simply connect via ssh and run the commands. In python you can do that using [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='foo', password='bar')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo hello")
```

Otherwise, you can use a python service, but you'll have to run it beforehand.
You can use Celery as previously mentioned, or [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq), or more simply use [RPyC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

Simply run the `rpyc_classic.py` script on the target machine, and then you can run python on it:

```
conn = rpyc.classic.connect("my_remote_server")
conn.modules.os.system('echo foo')
```

Alternatively, you can create a custom RPyC service (see documentation).

A final option is using an HTTP server like previously suggested. This may be easiest if you don't want to start installing everything. You can use [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) which is a simple HTTP framework in python:

Server-side:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/run_maya')
def index(name):
    # Do whatever
    return 'kay'

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Client-side:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://remote_server/run_maya')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would try and see what I get.

Comment: I downloaded rpyc and extracted it inside site packages but it doesn't work. When I run "import rpyc" it still gives and error as "No module named rpyc".

Answer (score 0):

One last option for cheap rpc is to run maya.standalone from a a maya python ("mayapy", usually installed next to the maya binary).  The standalone is going to be running inside a regular python script so it can uses any of the remote procedure tricks in KimiNewts answer.

You can also create your own mini-server using basic python.  The server could use the maya command port, or a [wsgi server](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server)  using the built in `wsgiref` module.  [Here](https://github.com/theodox/standaloneRPC) is an example which uses wsgiref running inside a standalone to control a maya remotely via http.

Comment: you dont get a gui thread with mayapy so you can not playblast. The gui is decoupled from the script layer, nothing says you can not run the server inside a gui maya tough. after all ive used maya to serve webpages many years ago with just mel.

Comment: masochist :) forgot he was playblasting, I always use cheap renders when not on my own machine

Answer (score 0):

We've been dealing with the same issue at work.  We're using Celery as the task manager and have code like this inside of the Celery task for playblasting on the worker machines.  This is done on Windows and uses Python.

```
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile
import textwrap

MAYA_EXE = r"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\maya.exe"

def function_name():
    # the python code you want to execute in Maya
    pycmd = textwrap.dedent('''
        import pymel.core as pm

        # Your code here to load your scene and playblast

        # new scene to remove quicktimeShim which sometimes fails to quit
        # with Maya and  prevents the subprocess from exiting
        pm.newFile(force=True)
        # wait a second to make sure quicktimeShim is gone
        time.sleep(1)
        pm.evalDeferred("pm.mel.quit('-f')")
        ''')
    # write the code into a temporary file
    tempscript = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, dir=temp_dir)
    tempscript.write(pycmd)
    tempscript.close()
    # build a subprocess command
    melcmd = 'python "execfile(\'%s\')";' % tempscript.name.replace('\\', '/')
    cmd = [MAYA_EXE, '-command', melcmd]
    # launch the subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.wait()
    # when the process is done, remove the temporary script
    try:
        os.remove(tempscript.name)
    except WindowsError:
        pass
```